# Запятая перед "что" в значении "который"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?
Пример:
Дорога (?) что никуда не ведёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Дорога, что никуда не ведёт.***

Запятая ставится.

Это определение в форме придаточного определительного предложения, ЧТО – союзное слово (= которая).